# Issue with communication between containers after deploying OPA with my application on GKE

Tags: java, yaml, google-kubernetes-engine, open-policy-agent

from my application side, I have a function named myfunction and via this function we can call OPA using its endpoint and the OPAinput as function parameters and it gives the response back through the “data” in “function(context, data)” section. This is how I call the function.

```
myfunction('http://localhost:8181/v1/data/play/policy', OPAinput , {
                  onSuccess : function(context, data) { 
        var permit = data.result.permit;
                      Log.info('permit '+ permit);
                  Log.info("Successfully posted data.");

},  onFail : function(context) {
                      Log.info("Failed to post data");
             }
  });
```

When I tested this function by running OPA with the application locally, it worked fine.But now I have deployed OPA with the application as a sidecar container on GKE, and I tried the same thing but it doesn't work. It says that

“Cannot get property "permit" of null     at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.error(ECMAErrors.java:57)     at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.typeError(ECMAErrors.java:213………….”

```
    This is the OPA logs
    
    2020-06-26 15:38:22.000 IST {"level":"info","msg":"Initializing server.","insecure_addr":"","diagnostic-addrs":[],"addrs":[":8181"]}
    2020-06-26 16:24:52.000 IST {"msg":"Received request.","req_path":"/v1/data/play/policy","req_id":1,"level":"info","req_method":"POST","client_addr":"127.0.0.1:39530"}
    2020-06-26 16:24:52.000 IST {"resp_status":200,"level":"info","req_method":"POST","req_id":1,"client_addr":"127.0.0.1:39530","req_path":"/v1/data/play/policy","resp_bytes":2,"msg":"Sent response.","resp_duration":9.564696}
```

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: rss-site
      namespace: myapp
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      minReadySeconds: 30
      strategy:
        rollingUpdate:
          maxSurge: 1
          maxUnavailable: 0
        type: RollingUpdate
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          deployment: myapp
          app: myapp
          pod: myapp
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            deployment: myapp
            app: myapp
            pod: myapp
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: opa
              image: openpolicyagent/opa:latest
              ports:
                - name: http
                  containerPort: 8181
              args:
                - "run"
                - "--ignore=.*"  # exclude hidden dirs created by Kubernetes
                - "--server"
                - "/policies"
              volumeMounts:
                - readOnly: true
                  mountPath: /policies
                  name: example-policy
            - name: myapp
              image: nickchase/myapp:v1
              ports:
                - containerPort: 9763
                  protocol: TCP
              volumeMounts:
                - name: identity-server-conf
                  mountPath: /home/myapp/myapp-config-volume/repository/conf/deployment.toml
                  subPath: deployment.toml
              serviceAccountName: "myappsvc-account"
            volumes:
              - name: myapp-server-conf
                configMap:
                  name: myapp-server-conf
              - name: example-policy
                configMap:
                  name: example-policy
```

```
Could you please help me to identify this issue :(
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I tested this function by running OPA with the application locally, it worked fine.But now I have deployed OPA with the application as a sidecar container on GKE, and I tried the same thing but it doesn't work. It says that

If it works locally and not in GKE that means something is different. Since it gives back a HTTP 200 response then likely the OPA container is running OK, but that either the policy, input, or data is different than what you had running locally.

Try enabling the console decision logger via `--set=decision_logs.console=true` with the OPA args. This will show you in the log output for OPA what the input it received was as well as the result it sent back. That should help guide the investigation.

I would also double check that all of the policies and data have been loaded into OPA in the same way as you had locally. Differences in the directory paths can affect any `*.json`/`*.yaml` files loaded, and potentially if you had any missing or otherwise different `*.rego` files it would affect the result as well.